# Can I use new Parse App API for upload iOS Push Certificates?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm wondering if I could use the new parse app api, for update information about ios certificates, more precisely, to upload them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by their [Apps API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#apps).

Edit: Here is a list of what is supported via the endpoint:

Enabling/Disabling...

- ...Client Side Class creation
- ...Client Push
- ...Revokable sessions
- ...Revoking a session on password chang